# Calendar events triggering an intent?

Tags: java, android, api, android-intent, calendar

I am writing an app and basically i need to know if there is some way to trigger an intent from my app upon an added calendarevent in google's built-in calendar.
Just to be clear, I wouldn't want my app running in the background. The added calendarevent would trigger my app to wake up.

Cheers,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar app does not send an intent when an event is added. All you can do is read and write calendar data using intents as described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents